# ARKit ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration cannot find in scope

Tags: swift, arkit

I am a newbie IOS Developer. When I'm working with ARKit, I get a compiler error:

> Cannot find 'ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration' in scope

Where is `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` in Swift 5.5?

[image: my code]

I tried `import ARKit`, but I can't pass the problem.

Comment: Please always post code as highlighted text, not image. This makes it easier to find, analyze and test your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am newbie to using Stackoverflow, and my English is not good, hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/markdaws/arkit-by-example/issues/7):

> **ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration**
>
> > Deprecated
> >
> > This class has been renamed in iOS 11 beta 5 and will not be available under its former name in iOS 11.0. Use ARWorldTrackingConfiguration instead.
> > https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingsessionconfiguration
>
> Replacing ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration with ARWorldTrackingConfiguration gets rid of the Xcode issue

The mentioned developer link is not working.

So, **use [`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration) instead.**